# Blur the Half of the image in react-native

Tags: react-native

i am using this [module](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-blur) for displaying blur image. My question is blur is applied to bottom of the image. This issue is faced in Android but iOS working fine. 
Please follow this issue in GitHub:- [enter link description here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-blur/issues/300)
Here is the screenshots:-
Android:-
[image]
iOS:- 
[image]

Answer (score -2):

```
<View style={styles.container}>
     <Text>Hi, I am some unblurred text</Text>
     <Image source={{ uri: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300' }} style={styles.img} />
     <BlurView style={styles.blur} blurType="light" blurAmount={10} />
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
    position: 'relative',
    zIndex: 1
  },
  img: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'relative',
    height: '100%',
    zIndex: 2,
    width: '100%'
  },
  blur: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
    height: '30%',
    zIndex: 3
  }
});
```

Hi, Just a case of styling each of the elements, in this case, its 30% high, but you can alter that figure on your project to be 50% or whatever you need it to be.

Hope this helps.